# concatenate two database columns into one resultset column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I use the following SQL to concatenate several database columns from one table into one column in the result set:

`SELECT (field1 + '' + field2 + '' + field3) FROM table1`

When one of the fields is null I got null result for the whole concatenation expression. How can I overcome this?

The database is MS SQL Server 2008. By the way, is this the best way to concatenate database columns? Is there any standard SQL doing this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The SQL standard way of doing this would be:

```
SELECT COALESCE(field1, '') || COALESCE(field2, '') || COALESCE(field3, '') FROM table1
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('hello', null, 'world');
SELECT COALESCE(field1, '') || COALESCE(field2, '') || COALESCE(field3, '') FROM table1;

helloworld
```

Comment: @Steve What's with the double pipe? Shouldn't that just be + for SQL Server?

Comment: `||` is the SQL standard string concatenation operator. The question asked "Is there any standard SQL doing this?" and I was answering that question. Perhaps OP meant to ask "Is there any plain SQL way to do this?"

Comment: @Adrian, not just oracle. Lots of RDMSs follow the standard here. It is good to know it when you go and try to do `string + string` and it fails because you are on an unfamiliar RDMS. A good example of this is the most widely deployed database ever: sqlite3. (in use on every iPhone and Android device)

Comment: Well, I would like to be able to execute that SQL on any database. I am not sure whether standard or plain SQL should be called?

Comment: @jilt3d, the `||` will work on more databases, but as you can see at http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#functions-concat, there are lots of incompatibilities here.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately || doesn't work in my case - Error: Incorrect syntax near '|', Error code: 102. It seems that I need to use the plus sign. Thanks!

Comment: The question is tagged with `sql-server-2008` - || won't be effective for concatenating strings in sql server

Comment: Yeah, it should probably be stated that, for mssql, you should use +. It is tagged with an mssql tag, and mssql is mentioned in the question body as well. Other than that, this works great.

Answer (score 38):

If you were using SQL 2012 or above you could use the CONCAT function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(field1, field2, field3) FROM table1
```

NULL fields won't break your concatenation.

@bummi - Thanks for the comment - edited my answer to correspond to it.

Comment: the question is about SQLServer 2008 CONCAT was introduced with SQLServer 2012

Answer (score 14):

Normal behaviour with NULL is that any operation including a NULL yields a NULL...

```
- 9 * NULL  = NULL  
- NULL + '' = NULL  
- etc
```

To overcome this use ISNULL or COALESCE to replace any instances of NULL with something else..

```
SELECT (ISNULL(field1,'') + '' + ISNULL(field2,'') + '' + ISNULL(field3,'')) FROM table1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are having a problem with NULL values, use the COALESCE function to replace the NULL with the value of your choice.  Your query would then look like this:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(field1, '') + '' + COALESCE(field2, '') + '' + COALESCE(field3,'')) FROM table1
```

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DataCrunching.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use ISNULL to overcome it.

Example:

```
SELECT (ISNULL(field1, '') + '' + ISNULL(field2, '')+ '' + ISNULL(field3, '')) FROM table1
```

This will then replace your NULL content with an empty string which will preserve the concatentation operation from evaluating as an overall NULL result.

Answer (score 1):

If both Column are numeric Then Use This code

> Just Cast Column As Varchar(Size)

**Example:**

```
Select (Cast(Col1 as Varchar(20)) + '-' + Cast(Col2 as Varchar(20))) As Col3 from Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Cast Column As Varchar(Size)

If both Column are numeric then use code below.

Example:

```
Select (Cast(Col1 as Varchar(20)) + '-' + Cast(Col2 as Varchar(20))) As Col3 from Table
```

What will be the size of `col3` it will be 40 or something else