# MySql - use of ALIAS for multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, alias

I saw the following code:

```
SELECT 
    u.ID, u.username, u.active, u.email, u.admin, u.banned, 
    u.name AS groupmemberships 
FROM users u 
WHERE u.ID={$uid}
```

and was wondering where the official documentation about aliasing multiple columns was. W3schools (not the best source) as the only place where I found "documentation" in the following way:

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name AS alias_name;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

I would appreciate a link to official documentation so I can look it over.

Comment: Is it aliasing multiple columns? Looks like this will just alias `u.name AS groupmemberships` the other columns will still be whatever they're normally called.

Comment: I agree with @Taryn East, and we generally use alias when joining tables.

Comment: Robert, there are hundreds of on-line explanations of SQL, and dozens of them are official (because it is provided by many softwares; some differences, but not great).  Suggest you run a search on keywords `MySQL ALIAS`.

Comment: You can alias an expression or column, such as in `select u.id as user_id` and `select upper(u.username) as uppercase_name`, and you can alias a table as in `from users u`. There exists no group alias for multiple columns. Does this answer your question? Well, you haven't really asked a question, though ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the same alias for multiple columns, but you can concatenate values and give the result an alias:

```
SELECT 
  u.ID, u.username, u.active, u.email, u.admin, u.banned, 
  u.name + u.username AS groupmemberships 
FROM users u
```

If this is what you want, then check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6427764/122139) for how to deal with null values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` function to get single alias for multiple columns,

```
 select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as employee_name from user;
```