# MySQL combine two columns into one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a way to combine two columns into one, but keep getting the value '0' in the column instead to the combination of the words.

These are what I've tried as well as others:

```
SELECT column1 + column2 AS column3
FROM table;

SELECT column1 || column2 AS column3
FROM table;

SELECT column1 + ' ' + column2 AS column3
FROM table;
```

Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What database are you using?  What are the types of the two columns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [concatenate two database columns into one resultset column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427764/concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427764/concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column

Comment: Use top answer's solution but add a pipe. select concat(column1, '|', column2). It helps in excel later

Answer (score 229, accepted):

My guess is that you are using MySQL where the `+` operator does addition, along with silent conversion of the values to numbers.  If a value does not start with a digit, then the converted value is `0`.

So try this:

```
select concat(column1, column2)
```

Two ways to add a space:

```
select concat(column1, ' ', column2)
select concat_ws(' ', column1, column2)
```

Comment: i am using `sql server 2005` and it is giving me error as `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: @coder . . . This question is tagged "mysql".  If you have a question about SQL Server, then ask it as a question, not in a comment.

Comment: Works for T-SQL as well, excellent and simple solution. Reduces two columns into one.

Answer (score 34):

Try this, it works for me

```
select (column1 || ' '|| column2) from table;
```

Comment: This looks like Oracle.

Comment: This worked for combining multiple (more than 2) columns too. Thx

Comment: The SQL standard provides the CONCAT() function to concatenate two strings into a single string.
SQLite, however, does not support the CONCAT() function. Instead, it uses the concatenate operator (||) to join two strings into one.

Answer (score 18):

It's work for me

```
SELECT CONCAT(column1, ' ' ,column2) AS newColumn;
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the only solution that would work for me, when I required a space in between the columns being merged.

```
select concat(concat(column1,' '), column2)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are Working On `Oracle` Then:

```
SELECT column1 || column2 AS column3
FROM table;
```

OR

If You Are Working On MySql Then:

```
SELECT Concat(column1 ,column2) AS column3
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 3):

For the MySQL fans out there, I like the `IFNULL()` function.  Other answers here suggest similar functionality with the `ISNULL()` function in some implementations.  In my situation, I have a column of descriptions which is `NOT NULL`, and a column of serial numbers which may be `NULL` This is how I combined them into one column:

```
SELECT CONCAT(description,IFNULL(' SN: ', serial_number),'')) FROM my_table;
```

My results suggest that the results of concatenating a string with `NULL` results in a `NULL`.  I have been getting the alternative value in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this way and Its a best forever. In this code null also handled

```
SELECT Title,
FirstName,
lastName, 
ISNULL(Title,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(LastName,'') as FullName 
FROM Customer
```

Try this...

Answer (score 1):

table:

```
---------------------
| column1 | column2 |
---------------------
|   abc   |   xyz   |
---------------------
```

In `Oracle`:

```
SELECT column1 || column2 AS column3
FROM table_name;
```

Output:

table:

```
---------------------
| column3           |
---------------------
| abcxyz            |
---------------------
```

If you want to put `','` or `'.'` or any string within two column data then you may use:

```
SELECT column1 || '.' || column2 AS column3
FROM table_name;
```

Output:

table:

```
---------------------
| column3           |
---------------------
| abc.xyz           |
---------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(varchar, column_name1) + (varchar, column_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Column1 + ' - ' + Column2 AS 'FullName' FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   CONVERT (nvarchar (10), Month(NextDate))+'-'+CONVERT (nvarchar (10), Year(NextDate)) as MonthOfYear, COUNT(CaseNo) as CountDisposal
FROM dbo.Main_Cause_List 
WHERE (DisposalState = 'Dispossed-off') 
GROUP BY Month(NextDate),Year(NextDate);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is over 7 years old) with existing answers. How does this answer improve over what's already here?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `coalesce()` and `concat()` to combine columns in the SQL query.

Assume that you have 4 columns **(id, name, phone_number, country_code)** in a **user** table and you want to print phone number in this format: **+countrycodephonenumber**

Eg: 1, vishnu, 9961907453, 91 will return phone number as +919961907453.

You can use the following query to get the above result.

```
select coalesce(concat('+', country_code, phone_number)) from user;
```