# How do I update a VARCHAR column so that it contains the contents of two other VARCHAR columns, separated by a space?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL, which is perhaps why I have not been able to locate a solution to the following problem.

I have this database table where all columns are of type `VARCHAR(50)`:

[image: f]

And I want to update the values in `FullName` so that they are a combination of `FirstName` and `LastName`, separated by a space.

This is what I would like to end up with:

[image: f]

I do not want to update each row manually.

Comment: Do you want to provide code samples?

Comment: I tried almost everything from this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/sql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column

Comment: I must not delete any of the columns, I must have the one column where the two values a merged.

Comment: Please show us the definition of your table (esp. the types of its columns).

Comment: The datatype of the columns is navchar(50).

Comment: @emo SIDE NOTE :> when thinks like a DBA I would suggest you to avoid the use of `FullName` _column_ in your table, why allocating extra data on database because you can simple get the `FullName` anytime using `select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as Fullname from yourTable`(I dont know whats your dev environment or requirements, its just a suggestion :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I do not want to update each row manually.*

I will show you two solutions:

1. **`UPDATE` the column with a single statement.** It's not really such a hassle:

   ```
   UPDATE Names
   SET FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
   -- or:     … = CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName);
   ```

   You said that all your columns are defined as `VARCHAR(50)`, so take note that `FirstName + ' ' + LastName` could reach a maximum length of 50 + 1 + 50 = 101 characters. Therefore there is the possibility that `FullName` gets truncated: That column will only store the first 50 characters (or less); if there are more, they get thrown away. So you might want to re-define `FullName` as `VARCHAR(101)`.
2. Alternatively, **turn `FullName` into a computed column:**

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Names
   DROP COLUMN FullName;

   ALTER TABLE Names
   ADD FullName AS (FirstName + ' ' + LastName);
   ```

   This solution has three distinct advantages:

   1. `FullName` can never contradict `FirstName` and `LastName`, because it is automatically derived (at the time of querying it) from them via the specified expression.
   2. There is no danger of string truncation, as with the above solution. Note that you do not need to specify a type for `FullName`; SQL Server figures it out automatically, based on the expression.
   3. `FullName` will not take up any storage space (unless perhaps when it is included in an index).

Comment: Hmm, I think that this will work, I just tested it, only "issue" is that there is to much space in the FullName column between the names.

Comment: @emo: Then `RTRIM(FirstName)` and `LTRIM(LastName)`. MSDN reference pages: [`LTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx), [`RTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx)

Comment: stakx thanks, it solved the spacing problem. Thanks guys. I would love to give some up-votes, but I cant.

Comment: And from now on I will always use Transaction, to avoid mistakes.

Comment: @emo: You're welcome. Feel free to return here & upvote once you have sufficient reputation. And oh, trust me, you can make mistakes *even with* transactions… ;-)