# Total number of yes and no values from mysql database table row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with 48 columns. The values in the table will be either "yes" or "no". I want to get the number of yes's and no's from a row.

For example:

One row having 23 Yes's and 25 No's, then it should display the total count at the front end
[image]

Comment: ````SELECT answer, count(*)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY answer```` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The count should be based on the row.

Comment: Stop. Step away from the machine. Start again.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following table

```
 id     answer    
 ------------
 1        YES   
 2        NO   
 3        YES
```

The query will be..

```
select sum(if(answer='YES',1,0))as yes,
sum(if(answer='NO',1,0))as no from test;
```

You will get the answer like below

```
+------+------+  
| yes  | no   |
+------+------+
|    5 |    1 |
+------+------+
```

If you want to get the result row by row please apply group by with the query..

```
 select id,sum(if(answer='YES',1,0))as yes,
 sum(if(answer='NO',1,0))as no from test group by id;
```

So the result will be

```
+------+------+
| yes  | no   |
+------+------+
|    2 |    0 |
|    2 |    0 |
|    1 |    1 |
```

Answer (score 3):

So your table is like this:

```
 id      p_id       answer1  answer2  answer3 ....etc
 --------------------------------------------------
 1       123        yes      no       yes
```

Don't do that! This is not how relational databases work. You store serial data in rows, not in columns. It will be much better to normalize the table and store each answer in a separate row:

```
 p_id     answer  value
 -----------------------
 123      1       yes
 123      2       no
 123      3       yes
```

Now you can easily count `yes/no` answers for a specific ID:

```
SELECT value, COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE p_id=123 GROUP BY value
```

If you have to stick with your current structure, the only reasonable option is to `SELECT *` and do the counting in php. There's no direct way in Mysql to count values on a per-column basis.

Comment: Georg, i will update my question with my database table screenshot then you can understand easily what's the requirement

Comment: i want to get the total number of yes and no from that one row

Comment: @user2372469: If you have to stick with your current structure, the only reasonable option is to SELECT * and do the counting in php.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1 + col2 + ... + col48 as yes, * FROM table_name
```

I'm hoping your table structure will support this;

I've never tried it, but I'm taking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22739860/4154967) as a reference.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention- if you change columns to an emun most of your code will probably still work, and my query will do the trick (just make sure no is first in the enum)

Answer (score 0):

The only realistic way to do it with your current structure is checking each column and adding 1 if 'Yes' and 0 if 'No'.

```
SELECT id, p_id,
        IF(Analysis1 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis2 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis3 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis4 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis5 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis6 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis7 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis8 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis9 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis10 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis11 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis12 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis13 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis14 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis15 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis16 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis17 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis18 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis19 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis20 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis21 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis22 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis23 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis24 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis25 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis26 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis27 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis28 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis29 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis30 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis31 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis32 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis33 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis34 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis35 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis36 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis37 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis38 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis39 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis40 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis41 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis42 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis43 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis44 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis45 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis46 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis47 = 'Yes', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis48 = 'Yes', 1, 0) AS YesCnt,
        IF(Analysis1 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis2 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis3 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis4 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis5 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis6 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis7 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis8 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis9 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis10 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis11 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis12 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis13 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis14 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis15 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis16 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis17 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis18 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis19 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis20 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis21 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis22 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis23 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis24 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis25 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis26 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis27 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis28 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis29 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis30 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis31 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis32 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis33 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis34 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis35 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis36 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis37 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis38 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis39 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis40 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis41 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis42 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis43 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis44 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis45 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis46 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis47 = 'No', 1, 0) +
        IF(Analysis48 = 'No', 1, 0) AS NoCnt
FROM iv_checklist
```

If the database was better designed, with these columns each as a row on a separate table then this would be very simple and fast to do.

Comment: It surely was a lot of fun typing that ))

Comment: Not going to type that much, way too lazy! Write one line, copy it 10 time and get the 1 to 10 versions. Then copy those 10 lines 5 times and just tazz down adding the digit for tens. Then copy / paste the whole lot for 'No' and select it, and change 'yes' to 'no' in the selection.