# SQL many to many subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30600/2) which shows my current query:

I’d prefer to display one line for each contact+location association, and group all the roles. So instead of 5 results, I would have 2 - one result for each unique location+contact combination, and all the roles of that contact combined into an array or something.

Not sure if this possible with raw SQL.

Desired results based on schema:

```
location 1        ryan       accountant, admin
location 2        steve      admin, manager, developer
```

Only locations with a contact should show.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/mysql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_agg`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/30600/25)

```
SELECT 
  locations."name", 
  contacts.name, 
  array_agg(roles."name") AS "Roles"
FROM locations INNER JOIN contacts ON locations."id" = contacts.location_id
   INNER JOIN "public".memberships ON "public".memberships.contact_id = contacts."id"
   INNER JOIN roles ON "public".memberships.role_id = roles."id"
 group by locations."name", contacts.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       locations."id", 
       locations."name", 
       contacts.name
FROM locations 
JOIN contacts ON locations."id" = contacts.location_id
```

Comment: That should do it for you.   No need for the other joins.  The distinct command helps filter out multiple similar results.

Comment: Ah sorry, just re-read you need to join the other fields.give me 2 minutes.

Comment: Sorry the code I use for this is MSSQL Based. See here:https://codemonkeycaffeine.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/sql-joining-rows-into-a-single-field/