# Case when a value is different to other value, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have this table structure for table `prices`:

```
CREATE TABLE prices
(
     id int, 
     priceFrom int, 
     priceUp int
);

INSERT INTO prices (id, priceFrom, priceUp)
VALUES (1, 23, 23), (2, 0, 0), (3, 12, 13),
       (4, 40, 40), (5, 15, 15), (6, 0, 0);
```

This is the result:

[image]

I have this query:

```
select 
    pricefrom, priceup,
    case
        when pricefrom = 0 then null
        when priceFrom <> priceUp then priceFrom + ' - ' + priceUp
        when priceFrom = priceUp then priceFrom
    end as FinalPrice
from 
    prices
```

what I need is to do a case when

1. pricefrom = 0 then show null
2. pricefrom = priceup then show the price
3. At least if pricefrom != priceup I want to show for example this: 12(pricefrom) - 13(priceup)

but in my query in this line:

[image]

I try to do this with `<>` but in the result appears the sum for both numbers:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: `when priceFrom <> priceUp then cast(priceFrom as varchar) + ' - ' + cast(priceUp as varchar)`?

Comment: `Cast` to `Varchar`

Comment: And cast the `THEN priceFrom` on the line below too.  *Don't* have multiple different data-types coming out of a `CASE` statement.  Implicit conversions are a bugger.

Comment: Each row in a column must have the same [data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187752.aspx).  The problem here is your column `FinalPrice' mixes integer and text rows.  To address use [cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) to convert the integer values to text.

Comment: Kind of a side note: if you have a code base (like a web app) that consumes this data and presents it somewhere (which is normally how you present data from the DB), it may be better to simply fetch the values directly and let the presentation code handle this logic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for the **concat** function here.

```
 select pricefrom, priceup,
case
when pricefrom = 0 then null
when priceFrom <> priceUp then concat(priceFrom, ' - ', priceUp)
when priceFrom = priceUp then cast(priceFrom as varchar(8))
end as FinalPrice
from prices
```

This link will probably be helpful

[MySQL combine two columns into one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/mysql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column/22739860#22739860)

Comment: @aakashgupta.0205 I get this error message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12 - 13 'to data type int.

Comment: My apologies. A case statement can only return one data type. Can you try now?

Answer (score 6):

You have to `CAST` to `VARCHAR`:

```
select pricefrom, priceup,
       case
          when pricefrom = 0 then null
          when priceFrom <> priceUp then concat(cast(priceFrom as varchar(8)),
                                                ' - ', 
                                                cast(priceUp as varchar(8)))
          when priceFrom = priceUp then cast(priceFrom as varchar(8))
       end as FinalPrice
from prices
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't provide the error, but by the format of your `CASE EXPRESSION` I'm assuming it's throwing an error due to conversion.

You should use [`CAST to VARCHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) :

```
 select pricefrom, priceup,
       case
           when pricefrom = 0 then ''
           when priceFrom <> priceUp then CAST(priceFrom as varchar(10)) + ' - ' + CAST(priceUp as varchar(10))
           when priceFrom = priceUp then CAST(priceFrom as varchar(10))
      end as FinalPrice
 from prices
```

I'm not sure about the first `WHEN` , but you should know that :

usually the first condition of a `CASE EXPRESSION` will **determine** the type of the column, so, if the first `THEN` placing an integer, this column will be an integer.

since you are putting null value in it, I'm not sure which type the column will be evaluated to, so it can still throw an error, but you can give it a try :

```
           when pricefrom = 0 then null
```

**Note:** Like @aakashpugta.0205 answer, using `CONCAT()` the convertion is automatic, but you should know that `CONCAT()` is available on SQL-Server only since 2012, so in older versions that won't work!

Let me also reffer you to an intersting article about [`CASE EXPRESSION secrets`](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) .

Comment: then it will work because you have modified rest conditions

Answer (score 2):

You should cast the price fields as string so that SQL understands that you don't want to treat them as numbers and do a mathematical operation:

```
select pricefrom, priceup,
case
when pricefrom = 0 then null
when priceFrom <> priceUp then cast(priceFrom as varchar) + ' - ' + cast(priceUp as varchar)
when priceFrom = priceUp then priceFrom
end as FinalPrice
from prices
```

Comment: Your code give this error message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12 - 13 'to data type int.

Comment: @Esraa_92 Yes, the `priceFrom case` should also be `cast` as otherwise type coercion will occur.