# SQL Sum Using logic to choose Plus or Minus (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

Not sure if this is possible or not in straight SQL.

Is it possible to choose the operator for a sum using the likes of a CASE Statement or similar logic.

e.g.

```
select 
  (select 1 from dual) 
  (case when (select 1 from dual) = 1 then + else - end) 
  (select 2 from dual)
from dual
```

Thanks in return.

Comment: you have to concat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809000/case-when-a-value-is-different-to-other-value-sql-server

Comment: I think better post your problem than that query, you may get better solution in some other way if you provide your problem and what you need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` and `+` cannot be results of `CASE WHEN`, because they are not values. `-1` and `+1` however are. Multiply this `-1` or `+1` with the desired value in order to get the positive or negative value. E.g:

```
select case when type = 'withdrawal' then -1 else +1 end * value as balance_change
```

For your example:

```
select
  (select 1 from dual) +
  (case when (select 1 from dual) = 1 then +1 else -1 end) *
  (select 2 from dual)
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select   1  + (case when (select 1 from dual) = 1 then +1 else -1 end) from dual
```

I mean:

```
with
    sub_q as (
        select 2000 val1, -1500 val2 from dual
        union all
        select 1000 val1, +2000 val2 from dual
    )
select val1, val2, SIGN(val2) s, val1 + (case when SIGN(val2) = 1 then +val2 else -val2 end)  res
from sub_q
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could this be applied to sub queries crude example e.g. select -1500   (case when sign((select -100 from dual)) = -1 then + else - end)  2000 from dual  ....  I want to do a calculation with some subqueries without having to put the sub queries in multiple times if that makes sense.The value - 1500 and 2000 would be derived from sub selects.