# How to convert 40302402 into 40/302/4/02 with the help of Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Convert '4030240201' into '40/3/02/40/201' using query.

I tried to convert '4030240201' into '40/3/02/40/201' using query but failed to do so. I am having the position and digits to be picked from a table.

Can this be done by the recursive query? How?

```
With Recursive s As (
  select fd.ilevel_pos, fd.ilevel_digits, substr(trim('4030240201'), ilevel_pos::Integer, ilevel_digits::Integer) || '/' as test 
  from index_detail fd
    join index_format lf on fd.formatid = lf.format_id and lf.activeFlag = 1
  Where ilevel_pos <= length(Trim('4030240201'))
    And ilevel_pos = 1
  Union All
  select fd.ilevel_pos, fd.ilevel_digits, substr(trim('4030240201'), fd.ilevel_pos::Integer, fd.ilevel_digits::Integer) || '/' as test 
  from index_detail fd
    join index_format lf on fd.formatid = lf.format_id and lf.activeFlag = 1
    join S ON (s.ilevel_pos = fd.ilevel_pos)
  Where fd.ilevel_pos <= length(Trim('4030240201'))
)
Select test 
From s;
```

```
Contents of the table index_detail

╔═════════════╦═══════════════╗
║  ilevel_pos ║ ilevel_digits ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════╣
║           1 ║             2 ║
║           2 ║             1 ║
║           3 ║             2 ║
║           5 ║             2 ║
║           7 ║             1 ║
║           8 ║             3 ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

I expected '40/3/02/40/201', but the actual output is '40/'

Comment: If this is an important operation I'd suggest [defininig a function to do it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createfunction.html) so you can be sure it works consistently and so your queries aren't huge and difficult to read.

Comment: What is the rule to do that? Why isn't it `403/024/02` or `40/30/24/02`?

Comment: How many rows? Is the position or the numner of `/` fixed? Can yo create a fiddle?

Comment: Btw, there's `select to_char(CAST('40302402' AS BIGINT), '09/999/9/99')`

Comment: @tadman thanks for the suggestion I used the function, but to avoid the multiple for loops i tried with the Query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name rules are set in the table index_detail

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand that table. What is `ilevel_pos` supposed to be? If that is the starting point in the string, then your table data doesn't match your expected output. Because the second "part" would overlap with the first part. The first part consist of the characters starting the first character with a length of two, so that would be `40`. And the second part starts with the second character and a length of one so that would be `0` not `3`. But if that is just an "ordering" column, then why does it have gaps?

Comment: The table also seems to define 6 parts whereas your expected output only contains 5 parts

Comment: If the input data was meant to be different, did you maybe mean something like this: https://rextester.com/VQLI79625

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding your question correctly why not just use the positions inside the substring.

```
with list as ( select '40231' as test, 2 as pos, 3 as leng) 
select substring(test, pos, leng) from list
```

EDIT:

```
with list as ( select '40302402' as test, 1 as pos1, 2 as leng1,3 as pos2, 3 as leng2) 
select substring(test, pos1, leng1)+'/' + substring(test, pos2, leng2)+'/' from list

with testing as ( select '40302402' as test, 1 as pos1, 2 as leng1,3 as pos2, 3 as leng2) 
select substring(test, pos1, leng1)+'/' + substring(test, pos2, leng2)+'/' from testing
```

for postgres would have to change concat operator

```
with testing as ( select '40302402' as test, 1 as pos1, 2 as leng1,3 as pos2, 3 as leng2) 
select substring(test, pos1, leng1) || '/' || substring(test, pos2, leng2) ||'/' from testing
```

Comment: You need to include a formated version of the sting as "40/302/4/02"

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I made an edit to my answer is this what you are referring to?

Comment: yes, however why are you using a list? also, does this compile?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I'm not using a list, it's just a generic name for the CTE. It runs on MSSQL just fine, I will add two more edits to show what I mean by name of CTE and change to use PostgreSQL concat

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry, little busy

Answer (score -1):

Try Declaring a variable containing the "40302402" value as input_value

then try doing a select of continue substr's

then join each item into a single line.

`SET input_value := '40302402';` (This May Need To Be Fixed)

`SELECT (
    SELECT concat(T.Var1, '/', T.Var2, '/', T.Var3, '/', T.Var4)
    FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(input_value, 1, 2) AS Var1,
        SUBSTRING(input_value, 3, 3) as Var2,
        SUBSTRING(input_value, 5, 1) as Var3,
        SUBSTRING(input_value, 6, 2) as Var4
    ) AS T
) as FormatedValue;`

The Above is **Untested** using the variable.

The **Hardcoded** version (below) works 100%

`SELECT (
    SELECT concat(T.Var1, '/', T.Var2, '/', T.Var3, '/', T.Var4)
    FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING('40302402', 1, 2) AS Var1,
        SUBSTRING('40302402', 3, 3) as Var2,
        SUBSTRING('40302402', 5, 1) as Var3,
        SUBSTRING('40302402', 6, 2) as Var4
    ) AS T
) as FormatedValue;`

Regards
Dean.

refs:

- [func_mysql_substring](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp)
- [mysql-combine-two-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/mysql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column/22739860)

Comment: was using the https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_substring site for testing code, lol