# How to search for string in a co-joined database column

Tags: php, search

I have this database table

```
id    | fName       | lName
1     | John        | Peter
2     | Bryan       | Mark
3     | Tony        | Dee
```

Now I have a search input for users to search names. I use this query to do my search Which works fine

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE (fName LIKE '".$search."' OR lName LIKE '".$search."')
```

But maybe when the user types something like `tony dee`, how can I run my query to search for the `fName` and `lName` column co-joined with a **space** so my query can return row 3.

I tried doing it like this

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE (fName LIKE '".$search."' OR lName LIKE '".$search."' OR fName ' ' lName LIKE '".$search."')
```

But the trick is not working out. Anyone with a better idea?

Comment: You need to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/mysql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column to get your SQL correct.  Although not sure if it is the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: If you really need this functionality, then I would suggest maintaining a third column which contains the concatenated first and last name.  This would make it more likely that any index could be used.

Comment: You can keep the first name and last name in two separate variables. and search by them

Comment: Use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split `tony dee` into `tony` and `dee`.  (But, what to do with `John F. Kennedy` or `Lyndon B. Johnson` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
"SELECT id,fName,lName FROM table WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',fName, lName) REGEXP(Peter|Tony)"

$t = 'Peter|Ton';
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',fName, lName) REGEXP(".$t.")"
```