# Combining duplicate SQLite columns after joining parent with multiple children

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a SQLite database set up which looks like this:[image]

I'm currently looking to join all of the child tables into the parent table. As you can see, all of the children are designed in the same way, so I was hoping that they would merge nicely together.
Unfortunately, joining the tables with a left join results in this:[image]

With SQLite, is it possible to merge the columns so that the null values are ignored, and the remaining starting_item_ids and item_ids all display in the same column?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here's a minimal reproducible example

```sql
CREATE TABLE `starting_item` (
  `starting_item_id` integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `quantity` integer
);

CREATE TABLE `starting_weapon` (
  `starting_item_id` integer,
  `item_id` integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (`starting_item_id`) REFERENCES `starting_item` (`starting_item_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `starting_armor` (
  `starting_item_id` integer,
  `item_id` integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (`starting_item_id`) REFERENCES `starting_item` (`starting_item_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `starting_gear` (
  `starting_item_id` integer,
  `item_id` integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (`starting_item_id`) REFERENCES `starting_item` (`starting_item_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `starting_tool` (
  `starting_item_id` integer,
  `item_id` integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (`starting_item_id`) REFERENCES `starting_item` (`starting_item_id`)
);


INSERT INTO starting_item (quantity) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO starting_item (quantity) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO starting_item (quantity) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO starting_item (quantity) VALUES (1);


INSERT INTO starting_weapon (starting_item_id, item_id) VALUES (1, 4);
INSERT INTO starting_armor (starting_item_id, item_id) VALUES (2, 7);
INSERT INTO starting_gear (starting_item_id, item_id) VALUES (3, 30);
INSERT INTO starting_tool (starting_item_id, item_id) VALUES (4, 20);


select * from starting_item 
    left join starting_weapon on starting_weapon.starting_item_id = starting_item.starting_item_id
    left join starting_armor on starting_armor.starting_item_id = starting_item.starting_item_id
    left join starting_gear on starting_gear.starting_item_id = starting_item.starting_item_id
    left join starting_tool on starting_tool.starting_item_id = starting_item.starting_item_id
```

Current result:

```
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+
| starting_item_id | quantity | starting_item_id | item_id | starting_item_id | item_id | starting_item_id | item_id | starting_item_id | item_id |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+
|                1 |        1 |                1 |       4 |                  |         |                  |         |                  |         |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+
|                2 |        1 |                  |         | 2                | 7       |                  |         |                  |         |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+
|                3 |        1 |                  |         |                  |         | 3                | 30      |                  |         |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+
|                4 |        1 |                  |         |                  |         |                  |         | 4                | 20      |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+
```

Intended Result:

```
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+
| starting_item_id | quantity | starting_item_id | item_id |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+
|                1 |        1 |                1 |       4 |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+
|                2 |        1 |                2 |       7 |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+
|                3 |        1 |                3 |      30 |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+
|                4 |        1 |                4 |      20 |
+------------------+----------+------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Please read the SQLite tag info and provide a [mre] as described there. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info Generally please prefer to provide textual information in textual form, not (only) as pictures of text. Make sure to provide a desired result for the provided tailored toy database.

Comment: Cheers @Yunnosch for the guidance, I've added in the current and expected results

Comment: Please double check. I suspect that the desired result you show is not what you really want. I would not want the duplicate columns and I would want an indication from which sub-table the "item_id" is, i.e. tool, gear, armor or weapon. Please understand, I think I could write a query to produce the current desired result, but I expect you to then change your mind. That would make an (unappreciated) "moving target question".

Comment: By the way, should I provide an answer I will not bother about the fancy "frames" and column headlines. Please state whether they are essential. They are helpful for understanding and readability, so please keep them. Just state whether they are required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL combine two columns into one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/mysql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column)

Comment: @Jere I challenge your duplicate. For tables as similarily structured as shown by OP that is inappropriate tinkering with string operations. I am about to make an answer in a few hours. Hope the question is not closed by then and that the desired output is more convincing by then.

Comment: @Yunnosch you may be correct about it not being necessary. I haven't really checked either way, I was just expecting it to be a simple answer, so if it's complicated at all I'd hold off on spending time on it, but thank you

Comment: It is not that I need hours for creating it. I have to do other things for some hours. If it gets  overly complicated I will let you know.

Comment: If you want 4 columns, select only 4 columns. Use [`coalesce`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) and/or [CASE expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_case_expression) to manipulate the date into shape.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus Interesting, plausible and in my opinon better than concating. Wouldn't you like to make an answer with code proposals? (I am thinking of something else and probably will still make my own answer...)

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for the kind words, I was just trying to give OP some ideas to play with. To me the example screams bill-of-materials or kits, so I have doubts about the data base design.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I can agree that the database design is pretty trash, I'm automating the database creation based off a large number of JSON files, so unfortunately I don't know if the database can be improved on much without a bunch of manual entry. It's for a system that was never designed to have a database made for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the stated desired output (minus frames, but that is just a config thing), with this query:

```sql
select * from starting_item a
join (      select * from starting_weapon
      union select * from starting_armor
      union select * from starting_gear
      union select * from starting_tool) b
on a.starting_item_id=b.starting_item_id;
```

It uses a multi "union" of the identically structured subtables and joins it with the starting item table, using aliases "a" and "b".

The result is quite exactly the stated desired output:

```
starting_item_id  quantity    starting_item_id  item_id
----------------  ----------  ----------------  ----------
1                 1           1                 4
2                 1           2                 7
3                 1           3                 30
4                 1           4                 20
```

However, in my opinion avoiding the redundant column (twice the ID) is desireable.
And I also feel somehow that a little trick to add an indicator (what kind of item we are seeing) is helpful. So I offer this for prettiness:

```sql
select * from starting_item
join (      select *, "weapon" kind from starting_weapon
      union select *, "armor"  kind from starting_armor
      union select *, "gear"   kind from starting_gear
      union select *, "tool"   kind from starting_tool)
using(starting_item_id);
```

It gets you, in case you like it:

```
starting_item_id  quantity    item_id     kind
----------------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1                 1           4           weapon
2                 1           7           armor
3                 1           30          gear
4                 1           20          tool
```

The first change is to join with `using()` instead of `on ...`, which (in spite of using `*`  for convenience) gets you only one ID column.
The second change is to add a column named "kind" with explicitly given content in each "unioned" part. This "unions" and "joins" up nicely and gets you a named indicator column. The advantage is that you can e.g. order by that indicator column for some tidyness.

Finally, please consider whether the unioned table used here is not actually something which you can use in your database design. I.e. use one table for all items, with an additional "kind" column.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Yunnosch, I ended up joining on a couple more tables and using your code and the coalesce function as suggested by @DinoCoderSaurus to get exactly what I was wanting from my final result. Cheers for all your help.