# How to select distinct value from two columns into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are two location related columns in my table like below

```
| Service_No | A_LOC | Z_LOC |
|------------|-------|-------|
| 001        | A     | B     |
| 002        | A     | C     |
| 003        | Null  | C     |
| 004        | F     | B     |
```

How do I select the distinct values of columns `A_LOC` and `Z_LOC` combined into a single list? The result of this query would be:

```
A, B, C, F
```

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DaleK I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/mysql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column/22739860), but it is about concatinating columns

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: @eshirvana I am not sure, how do I found out about the version

Comment: run `select @@version`

Comment: @eshirvana 2017

Comment: Do you want separate rows for distinct values or all one value concatenated together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select string_Agg(Location,',') as distinct_location_list
 from (
select A_LOC Location FROM tablename
union 
select Z_LOC Location FROM tablename
) tt
```

Comment: I don't need to join with ',', but I think union does the trick. Does union take care of the duplicates when combining the two columns?

Comment: @ddd yes it eliminates duplicates

Comment: `Location` is a Keyword in sql server. So, it would be nice not to use that keyword as alias. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think, I have a quick solution for you. However, you can optimize it or you can do it in different ways.

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE
(
Service_No VARCHAR(30),
A_LOC  VARCHAR(30),
Z_LOC  VARCHAR(30)
);
INSERT INTO  @YourTable Values('001','A','B');
INSERT INTO  @YourTable Values('002','A','C');
INSERT INTO  @YourTable Values('003',NULL,'C');
INSERT INTO  @YourTable Values('004','F','B');

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(FINALDATA  VARCHAR(30));

INSERT INTO @TempTable
SELECT A_LOC FROM @YourTable WHERE A_LOC IS NOT NULL;
INSERT INTO @TempTable
SELECT Z_LOC FROM @YourTable WHERE Z_LOC IS NOT NULL;

SELECT DISTINCT FINALDATA FROM @TempTable;
```

**Note:** This code is written in SQL SERVER. Please check the code and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively try this method if the string_agg function is not available.

```
select 
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + Loc FROM 
            (
            select distinct A_Loc  as Loc from @t 
            union 
            select distinct Z_Loc  as Loc from @t 
            ) t2 
          FOR XML PATH (''))
        , 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: This problem and the alternatives are well covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv/42778050#42778050

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend unpivoting using `apply` and then filtering and `distinct`ing:

```
select string_agg(loc, ',')
from (select distinct loc
      from t cross apply
           (values (a_loc), (z_loc)) v(loc)
      where loc is not null
     ) v;
```