# SQL Combine two Columns from one table into one

Tags: sql

This seemed simple, but I'm already using a temp table and can't think of how to combine my

```
With cte as

(select ID,
        TEST_DATE, 
        CATEGORY_A_TOTAL_TEST, 
        CATEGORY_B_TOTAL_TEST, 
        right(TEST_DATE,4) as Test_year
from TESTS) 

select cte.*, b.Average,b.NationalAverage
from cte
left join Averages b 
on cte.Test_year = b.Test_Year
```

I'm wanting to  have these columns to be called Total_Test in one column:
CATEGORY_A_TOTAL_TEST
CATEGORY_B_TOTAL_TEST

Can I union in a temp or use some sort of case?

Here's a sample:

```
CATEGORY_A_TOTAL_TEST
42
47
55
58
30
42
63
52
47
47

CATEGORY_B_TOTAL_TEST
42
47
55
58
30
42
63
52
47
47

Total_Test
42
47
55
58
30
42
63
52
47
47
41
46
54
57
30
41
63
51
47
47
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using?

Comment: Are you talking about concatenating two strings, e.g. 'My A test' and 'My B test' become 'My A test, My B test'? The standard string concatenation operator in SQL is `||`, hence: `category_a_total_test || ', ' || category_b_total_test`. In case your DBMS does not feature the standard string concatenation operator, look up the docs for your DBMS. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I think your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739841/mysql-combine-two-columns-into-one-column/22739860

Comment: On a side note: You are using a string function on a date. Are you really storing the dates as strings? You shouldn't.

Comment: Your question mentions two tables.  I don't see sample data for the two tables in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
DECLARE @tblTests TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Test_Date DATE,
    Category_A_Total_Test VARCHAR(MAX),
    Category_B_Total_Test VARCHAR(MAX),
    Test_Year VARCHAR(MAX)
);
INSERT INTO @tblTests
(
    Id,
    Test_Date,
    Category_A_Total_Test,
    Category_B_Total_Test,
    Test_Year
)
VALUES
(1, '2021-01-01', 'Cat A', 'Cat B', '2021');

DECLARE @tblAverages TABLE
(
    Test_Year VARCHAR(MAX),
    Average DECIMAL
);
INSERT INTO @tblAverages
(
    Test_Year,
    Average
)
VALUES
(   '2021', -- Test_Year - varchar(max)
    0.60    -- Average - decimal
    );



SELECT Tests.*,
       Averages.Average
FROM @tblTests AS Tests
    INNER JOIN @tblAverages AS Averages
        ON Tests.Test_Year = Averages.Test_Year;
```