# how to select not mentioned data by case when in (case1, case2, case3) ?

Tags: sql

Is there any way to select not mentioned data from case statement?

```
CASE 
 WHEN FRUIT_TYPE_CODE IN('001', '003','009') THEN '' 
 ELSE 'REG_DATE' 
END as OTHER
```

i would like to show "OTHER" should include: 002, 004,005,006,007,008.

How can i do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  In you CASE ELSE 002 would yield 'REG_DATE'. What do you want it to yield? Give brief example input and  desired output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [concatenate two database columns into one resultset column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427764/concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column)

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` expression can specify multiple `WHEN` clauses:

```
CASE
 WHEN FRUIT_TYPE_CODE IN('001','003','009') THEN ''
 WHEN FRUIT_TYPE_CODE IN('002','004','005','006','007','008') THEN 'OTHER'
 ELSE 'REG_DATE' 
END as OTHER
```

Or you can leave your existing query as-is, but change `ELSE 'REG_DATE'` to `ELSE 'OTHER'`.