# how to concatenate multiple column values into a single column?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, concatenation

i have the following table friend

```
id | first_name | last_name | gender | age | mobile
1  | bobby      | roe       | male   | 21  | 541-5780
```

how to concatenate multiple column (first_name & last_name) values into a single column to get the following result?

```
full_name
bobby roe
```

i have writen the following query but it does not work

```
declare @full_name varchar(max)
select @full_name = COALESCE(@full_name + ', ', '') + first_name, last_name
from friend
select @full_name
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [concatenate two database columns into one resultset column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427764/concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

Comment: what do you mean with 'it does not work'? any error? unexpected output? no output at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**More than one way to achieve this:**

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ' ,last_name) AS full_name;
```

**For earlier versions (Where CONCAT is not a built in function):**

```
SELECT first_name + ISNULL(' ' + last_name, '') as Full_Name from [YourTable]
```

**This as well should give you the same result**

```
SELECT COALESCE(first_name, '') + COALESCE(last_name, '') as FullName FROM [YourTable]
```