# Concat column values with comma as the separator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figure out the result of the below query on how to concat all the columns into a single string with comma separated values. The number of values can be dynamic.

```
SELECT 'Sc4','Sc5','Sc8','Sc7','Sc2'
```

I want the result to be as below:

```
Sc4,Sc5,Sc8,Sc7,Sc2
```

I have tried using stuff but did manage to concat the string but unable to insert comma in between.

Below is what i have tried

```
SELECT Stuff((SELECT 'Sc4','Sc5','Sc8','Sc7','Sc2' FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 0, '');
```

### UPDATE

I would like to rephrase my question, is there any way the out shown below can be converted to csv

[image: Result]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [concatenate two database columns into one resultset column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427764/concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column)

Comment: You should probably do this in your application though, the db isn't great for this kind of thing.

Comment: well if that was an option, i would have loved it. Due to some limitations, i have to do this within sql. @Andy

Comment: Fair enough, but it will have a negative impact on performance, so be aware.

Comment: Yup i am aware of that but for now this needs to be a workaround till we can do it in the application side.

Comment: Are you actually selecting 5 varchar fields or are you selecting from another table/query?  Seems like an odd requirement for a sql only approach.  Where is the data coming from?

Comment: please post some sample data and expected result

Comment: The place where the sql query is being built is part of the application that acts as the adaptor, so there is specific syntax that gives out parameters, so what i am trying to do is build up a csv with the parameters to be passed to a stored procedure. I know it is unusual requirement but i was wondering if there is a way to sort it out. The number of varchar values can vary and not fixed.

Comment: so where is the source data to build the csv ?

Comment: We'd love to help, but as is, it just doesn't make much sense.  An application that generates random sql -- where does that go?  Are you receiving a select statement in a stored procedure?  How are you actually executing the sql if you can't edit the application that is running it?

Comment: Is this a single row or are you trying to make something that looks like a CSV file from a table?

Comment: i have updated my question for the sake of clarity. There are somethings not under my control to change hence I am trying to leverage the bad design to meet a certain requirement. See the update section please.

Comment: is the Sc4, Sc5 etc stored some where ?

Comment: Please provide a more detailed sample data. Where did `sc1,2,3,4,5` come from?

Comment: The values are passed to the server from the user selected values. this is part of the application configuration where we can configure the data to be fetched from the sql server. So there is no code involved just configuring an sql query to be executed and resulted is passed to the UI.

Comment: so your front end application should be the one performing the string concatenation `Sc4,Sc5,Sc8,Sc7,Sc2` right ?

Comment: @Squirrel I agree, bad design, the front-end or the server is not under my control. All i can do is play around with the sql part to meet the requirement. :( sadly it does not seem like it is possible but i wanted to give it try by asking here

Comment: you said "The values are passed to the server from the user selected values" How are these value passed to the SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1):

i assume Sc4, Sc5 etc are your column name and not string constant ?

```
SELECT Stuff(
             (
                SELECT ',' + Sc4 + ',' + Sc5 + ',' + Sc8 + ',' + Sc7 
                     + ',' + Sc2 
                FROM   yourtable
                FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenation like

```
SELECT 'Sc4' + ',' + 'Sc5' + ',' + 'Sc8' + ',' + 'Sc7' + ',' + 'Sc2'
```

Comment: If it was so easy then i would not need to ask the question here :) what you have mentioned above will work if you know the values. I want to be build csv dynamically.

Comment: your question are that not clear. What you have posted seems like some string constant

Comment: @Dilberted please provide the correct info to avoid confusion. First question, what is your app built on? (asp, mvc etc.) If you are using c# you can convert your csv to datatable and from there, create a table valued type with the same format with the datatable in sql server 2008. you can now pass the datatable to stored procedure and cast it to your table type. See this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.90).aspx