# How to bind multiple data on one element (Gridview)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to bind multiple attributes from the database on my grid view, so I have (first name, middle name and last name) and I want to concatenate them in one column of my grid view (name)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV1" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label 
                    ID="edtName" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' 
                />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, how do I bind them?
I'm using visual studio 2013, asp.net with c#, Thanks.

Comment: you  can try doing something like `<%# Bind("firstname") %>+' '+<%# Bind("middlename") %>'+' '+'<%# Bind("lastname") %>'`

Comment: You can have multiple binds: `Text='<%# string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Bind("FirstName"), Bind("MiddleName"), Bind("LastName")) %>' `. Or change your query statement to concatenate all three to single string (`SELECT FirstName + MiddleName + LastName AS Name, ...`)

Comment: Dear Tetsuya Yamamoto, first way it didn't work with me, the exception message is (CS0103: The name 'Bind' doesn't exist in the current context).

Comment: @ShahadHassan I found that you cannot use `Bind` multiple times, but you can use `Eval` for all of these: `Text='<%# string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Eval("FirstName"), Eval("MiddleName"), Eval("LastName")) %>'`.

Comment: Yes it works right now, Thank you Mr. Yamamoto :)

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do that:

**1) Using string concatenation**

The string concatenation on `Text` property does not allow multiple `Bind` methods for data binding, hence `Eval` should be used here.

**`+` operator version**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="edtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("firstname") %> + ' ' + <%# Eval("middlename") %> + ' ' + <%# Eval("lastname") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**String.Format version**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="edtName" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Eval("FirstName"), Eval("MiddleName"), Eval("LastName")) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**2) Modify query with AS aliasing**

Use [`COALESCE` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427764/concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column) to combine all related fields into single string and give an alias which has same key as defined in label's `Bind`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(FirstName, '') || COALESCE(MiddleName, '') || COALESCE(LastName, '') AS Name FROM TableName ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Eval like below :

```
Text='<%# string.Concat(Eval("FirstName"), " ", Eval("LastName"))%>'
```