# PollyReports concatenation of columns

Tags: python, report

I am using Polly Reports for the report generation,
The sql statement is below

cur.execute("SELECT StdID, Firstname, Othername, Surname FROM STUDENT")

in PollyReports Elements I want to concatenate the fields Firstname Othername and Surname in the Band,

I wrote this 
 Element((100, 0),("Helvetica", 12), getvalue = lambda x: x(key=1 + " " + key=2 + " " +key=3) format = lambda x ),

am getting syntax error.

Please my interest is more in the use of the lambda and function (def) in the Element in PollyReports so that I can reuse the knowledge. Thanks

Comment: Please write your code in code format don't mix it with text.

Comment: If you'll only use firstname/othername/surname concatenated, why don't you just concatenate them in the query? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427764/concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is rather old, but as the author of PollyReports I felt I should weigh in.  Part of the line of code given doesn't make sense to me, specifically the body of the lambda function given as the getvalue parameter.  I'm also hampered by not knowing which database module you are using; are rows returned as lists/sequences or dicts?  I'm assuming each row is a list, and my answer assumes that.

```
Element((100, 0), ("Helvetica", 12), 
    getvalue = lambda row: "%s %s %s" % (row[1], row[2], row[3]))
```

There's no reason you'd need a format function here since the getvalue function is doing all the necessary formatting.  The syntax of the first lambda in the question is wrong, as x (the row) is almost certainly not callable (at least if it is in fact a list).  However, the syntax error is likely due to the missing comma before the format parameter OR the incomplete status of the lambda given for the format parameter.  You can't just say

```
format = lambda x
```

You'd need to say

```
format = lambda x: <some expression here>
```